# iOS Objective C sending and getting NSString from NSData

Tags: ios, objective-c, c

I've been developing a multiplayer game based on RayWenderlich's tutorial, my problem is that i cannot send any `NSString` over `NSData`, i've tried many ways of encoding and decoding (UTF8) etc, but i always get something similar to **\204**(upside down ?)**B**(upside down ?) when i do a `printf`on the receiving side, but when i do an NSLog says (null).

here's the modified parts of the **.h**

```
typedef struct {
    Message message;
    const char * theTeam;
} MessageGameBegin;
```

here's the **.m** code that's driving me nuts:

```
 (void)sendGameBegin:(NSString *) team {
    NSString *strSQL = [[NSString alloc]init];
    strSQL = team;
    const char *bar = [strSQL cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"HOOOOOE %@\n",[[NSString alloc] initWithCString:bar encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);

    MessageGameBegin message;
    message.theTeam = bar;
    message.message.messageType = kMessageTypeGameBegin;
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:&message length:sizeof(MessageGameBegin)];
    [self sendData:data];

}
```

then in the receive,

```
 ....else if (message->messageType == kMessageTypeGameBegin) {

    MessageGameBegin * beginMessage = (MessageGameBegin *) [data bytes];
    myDecoded = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:beginMessage->theTeam];
    NSLog(@"NSLOOOOOOOG %@\n",myDecoded);


    printf(" BEGING MESS %s\n",beginMessage->theTeam);
    CCLOG(@"cl BEGING MESS %@\n",myDecoded);

    [self setGameState:kGameStateActive];
    self.enemy = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:myDecoded];

}
```

the `NSLog(@"HOOOOOE %@\n..` doesn't even print into the console even though i'm 100% its executed
`NSLog(@"NSLOOOOOOOG %@\n"..` returns (null)
`printf` gives weird humanly unreadable outputs like i showed before
the CCSprite line cant find the file because it says its nil

I need to know what im doing wrong in this attempt to send **NSSTrings**, or even a better way to do it.. please i'd appreciate your help, i've been ripping my hair out for 2 days since i'm new to objective c

heres the tutorial i'm going off on, it has a source you can download at the bottom of the part2
http://www.raywenderlich.com/3276/how-to-make-a-simple-multiplayer-game-with-game-center-tutorial-part-12

**Edit:**
bottom line the whole goal is to be able to send and receive a string in data... and i gfailed miserably so help would a appreciated

@borrrden this is what i got from your help

sending:

```
MessageGameBegin message;
message.theTeam = bar;
message.message.messageType = kMessageTypeGameBegin;
//NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:&message length:sizeof(MessageGameBegin)];
NSMutableData *data = [NSMutableData new];
[data appendBytes:&message length:sizeof(MessageGameBegin)];
[data appendBytes:message.theTeam length:strlen(message.theTeam)];
data.length = sizeof(MessageGameBegin) + strlen(message.theTeam);
[self sendData:data];
```

receiving:

```
MessageGameBegin msg;
msg.theTeam = [[data subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(sizeof(msg.message.messageType), data.length-sizeof(msg.message.messageType))] bytes];

NSLog(@"NSLOOOOOOOG %@\n",[[NSString alloc] initWithCString:msg.theTeam encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
```

returns something that looks better (upside down ?)ІOarizona.png it seems like i got the data length wrong or something.. i want it to return arizona.png , it is constantly 3 characters off.. the 3 infront of arizona, so in this case would it be recomended to just trim off the 3 or is there another way?

Comment: Did you mean `length:sizeof(message)`? Your MessageGameBegin struct only needs to be big enough to hold your Message object (probably really just a pointer) and a pointer to a string array.

Comment: @AustinMullins honestly, im not sure what is causing the problem here.. i just thought since i put "theTeam" with the type def in the header file then gave it a string that it would be automatically be sent out when the message was sent. the whole goal is to be able to send and receive a string in data

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`sizeof` is not a magic function.  It doesn't automatically know how long your struct is in the heap.  It only knows how many bytes it takes up on the stack, which is however long `Message` is, plus 4 bytes for a char pointer.  So you will end up getting a pointer to where the data was on your original device, which when received on a new device will just be garbage (you are lucky it doesn't crash).  You need to encode the string directly into the `NSData` object, or just take the easier route and make a proper class.  I recommend making a class if you are going to be storing pointers.  Then you can just implement `NSCoding` to easily convert to and from `NSData`

**EDIT:**

If you *really* must do the struct yourself, you are going to have to manually put together `NSData`.  I still recommend simply making a class.

Let's say I have this struct:

```
typedef struct
{
    int testInt;
    const char *testString;
} SO2Test;
```

I can encode it like this:

```
SO2Test test;
test.testInt = 5;
test.testString = "TEST";
NSMutableData *data = [NSMutableData new];
[data appendBytes:&(test.testInt) length:sizeof(int)];
[data appendBytes:test.testString length:strlen(test.testString)];
data.length = sizeof(int) + strlen(test.testString);
```

This makes some severe assumptions about the string though such as endianness (which won't matter if you are sending between two iOS devices, since they will both be the same) and that the string is 1-byte per character.  If your string is UTF-16 for some reason, this will fail miserably, since it will potentially reach a NULL termination character early.  Can you see now why making a class will make your life much easier?  `NSString` will handle all of this nonsense for you.

If that is OK, then you can continue on the other side like this:

```
SO2Test test2;
int *intPtr = (int *)[[data subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, sizeof(int))] bytes];
test2.testInt = *intPtr;
test2.testString = [[data subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(sizeof(int), data.length-sizeof(int))] bytes];
```

Comment: how would i encode directly into the 'NSData' object? a general direction would be okay if your are unable to get specific

Comment: I edited my question with an example, but I don't suggest this way of doing it.  It will most certainly introduce bugs if the string is not properly formatted.

Comment: i think it'll work but im not done implementing, so for the future when i want life to be much much much easier, what type of class would i have to create for a function like this? @borrrden

Comment: Any class is fine...just make it conform to NSCoding and you can easily turn it into NSData with no mistakes.  It will probably just inherit from NSObject.

Comment: ok, im making great progress with your help and i am very greatful! i updated my original post, can you take a look at it? i believe the problem this time is length of the data in the receiving end @borrrden

Comment: That is beyond the scope of this question.  You need to ask a new one **and** provide a lot more info.  You are using structs within structs, so anyone trying to answer needs info about both structs.